# Present Android Activity similar to iOS 13 presentation?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I was wondering if there was an already built in way to present an activity similar to the iOS 13 option of modal presentation. I'm trying to achieve the same interactions including swiping the activity down to close and indication that there is an activity in the background. I've included some images below:

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You would not use an activity for that. My guess is that `BottomSheetDialogFragment` would be a candidate, but I am not an iOS user or developer, so there may be aspects of what you want that would match something else in Android better.